# slow internet access when routing via a server (both using iptables NAT and ssh tunnelling)

Tags: iptables, nat, ssh-tunnel

I have a spare computer powered by a dual core intel atom N550 CPU and 2GB RAM (I will refer this as "the server"). It is running lubuntu 14.10 x86 (32 bit) with lightdm service disabled (hence, no GUI). I use this computer as a gateway to the internet.

This computer has two NIC. One is a TPLink TL-WN722N, which is detected as wlan1 and is connected to the internet via wifi with a connection speed of approximately 10 mbps. The other NIC is Realtek RTL8101E Fast Ethernet adapter, which is detected as eth0. I share my internet connection to a desktop PC via this eth0 adapter. All connections are handled by NetworkManager. The eth0 is set to `method=shared`, which I believe add this entry to my iptables nat table :

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.42.0.0/24        !10.42.0.0/24
```

The problem is, when I download a certain file AT the server, I get the download speed of 10 mbps, so the connection from the server to the wifi should be okay. Transferring a file from the server to my desktop PC (via eth0, using SCP protocol) has the speed of 20mbps to 30mbps. But when I download directly the exact same file from my desktop PC, I only get speed of 2mbps to 4mbps. Proxying my download via an ssh tunnel (created using command `ssh -N -D 1080 user@10.42.0.1` is slightly faster, that is between 3 mbps to 4.5 mbps (yes, the speed is fluctuative). Ping roundtrip time doesn't seem to be affected much, only differs in 2ms.

Downloading more than one file at once from the internet also doesn't help. The combined speed is the same (e.g. : downloading 3 files from 3 different servers (but same datacenter), each file is downloaded at speed of approx. 1mbps, so the combined speed is approx. 3mbps).

FYI, this installation is a brand new installation, without any configuration changes on it (except the mentioned NetworkManager config, enabling sshd service on boot, and disable lightdm service on boot). Running `top` as root only shows that `kworker/u8+` process is using up to 5% of CPU usage when I am downloading from desktop PC, the rest is at near 0%. And my desktop PC is the only one who connects to this server.

Please help me. Thank you for the assistance, and sorry for my bad English grammar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me to be that your WLAN connection is the issue.  If your WLAN connection speed is reporting 10 megabits you will only get a fraction of that in reality, and I think that is what is happening.   I do wonder if your WLAN device is connected at 11 Mbps - 802.11b rather then 802.11g or n which could be a lot faster.

BTW, according to [this link](http://www.speedguide.net/faq/what-is-the-actual-real-life-speed-of-wireless-374) 2-3 Mbps is bang on the money for an 802.11b (11Mbps) connection.